# Only 2 pipes get spawned with my code but I want an infinite amount to spawn

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a runner game, like flappy bird.

Here is my code for spawning and drawing pipes :

```
pipe_surface = pygame.image.load('Assets/pipe-green.png')
pipe_list = []
SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT #IDK why this lacks function brackets
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1200)


def create_pipe():
  new_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (700,300))
  return new_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
  for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.centerx -= 5
    return pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
  for pipe in pipes:
    screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)
```

...

```
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
          pipe_list.append(create_pipe())

  move_pipes(pipe_list)    

    draw_pipes(pipe_list)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Can anybody recognise a mistake I am making that is causing a limited number of pipes to spawn ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to figure out where the problem lies? Are the new pipes added to `pipe_list`? Also ``#IDK why this lacks function brackets`` would imply that this isn't your code and you don't actually know how it works. Maybe if you try to work through the entire code and understand every bit you can ask a more focus question.

Comment: Hi there, I am a beginner to programming and am just trying to learn through examples. I have been here for 2 hours and still cant see where the problem lies. To me it seems that the new pipes are being added to the pipe_list through the create_pipe() function. Also, about the comment, from what I can tell, the only way of knowing that the function lacks brackets would be to view the functions structure in some kind of index, which I am unsure of how I would access and is well beyond my intentions with this small project.

Comment: Is it your entire code right there ?

Comment: "view the functions structure in some kind of index" That is called reading the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs). That should be a step long before asking a question on StackOverflow. Anyway, I found the problem.

Comment: It is not the entire code. I have just gave the part of the code for the pipes. Also, is it something to do with my functions ? Specifically is it to do with my "move_pipes" function ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie in the creation, but in the `move_pipes` function. A lot of pipes get created, but they are all in the same place. But only the first on moves, since your `move_pipes` function has an unnecessary return in the loop, making it only deal with the first entry. Just remove the return:

```
def move_pipes(pipes):
  for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.centerx -= 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! :) That has fixed the code. I am slightly confused, however, as to why the return does not work in my game, but works in the tutorial of the creator of the code:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZg49z76cLw   at 46.05 seconds.

Comment: @LewisH Because lists in python are passed by reference, which means that the pipes you pass as parameter are modified directly without creating a copy of the list which is local to the function, avoiding the need to return the pipes. Moreover, you are not storing the value returned by the function anywhere.

Comment: @LewisH I bet in the tutorial the return clause is un-indented once, so that the the function only returns after all the iterations are complete, because the return causes python interpreter to exit out from the function and move  on to the next line.